# Empty graph shown when using iplot from chart_studio insted of plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, choropleth

I am following a python tutorial about the use of plotly.

Here are some commands I have to run to import functions and methods I will use

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```

However, when I run commands on my jupyter nootbook, it says the use of plotly is deprecated and it recommends me to use the module chart_studio instead (error points to line `import plotly.plotly as py`):

> ImportError:  The plotly.plotly module is deprecated, please install
>   the chart-studio package and use the chart_studio.plotly module
>   instead.

So I run

```
pip install chart_studio
```

and try to replace the line above with functions and methods coming from the `chart_studio` module.

Here is my code:

```
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

data = dict(type= 'cloropleth', 
            locations = ['AZ','CA','NY'],
           locationmode = 'USA-states',
           colorscale = 'Portland',
           text = ['text 1','text 2','text 3'],
           z = [1,2,3],
           colorbar = {'Title':'Colorbar title goes here'})

mylayout = dict(geo={'scope':'usa'})

choromap = go.Figure(data = [data], layout=mylayout, skip_invalid=True)

iplot(choromap)
```

The problem is that, when running the final line `iplot(choromap)`, I get this empty graph

[image]

While in the tutorial this other graph appears

[image]

What is wrong?

Please note that I installed cufflinks-0.17.3 plotly-4.5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

In my code there were 2 errors:

at line

```
type= 'cloropleth',
```

I had the mispelled value `'cloropleth'`, where the correct value is `'choropleth'`,

and then at line

```
colorbar = {'Title':'Colorbar title goes here'})
```

I had `'Title'`, where the correct key is `'title'` (lowercase).

Fixed them and now the map is correctly displayed.

Also, it was not necessary to install `chart_studio`.

So in the end the correct code is:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

data = dict(type= 'choropleth', 
            locations = ['AZ','CA','NY'],
           locationmode = 'USA-states',
           colorscale = 'Portland',
           text = ['text 1','text 2','text 3'],
           z = [1,2,3],
           colorbar = {'title':'Colorbar title goes here'})

mylayout = dict(geo={'scope':'usa'})

choromap = go.Figure(data = [data], layout=mylayout)

iplot(choromap)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to cleanly install plotly?

Uninstall plotly using pip

```
!pip uninstall plotly
```

Then uninstall plotly using conda

```
!conda uninstall plotly
```

After that, install the last version using pip

```
!pip install plotly
```

check Plotly version

```
import plotly
plotly.__version__
```